# How do I use Vasm?

Tags: assembly, 6502

I have got the 6502 kit and now I wanted to start working with the assembler. I downloaded the zip, but I can't find a way to install/ access the files so I can use them. I am also not sure if I should use the command prompt or something else like python IDLE. Could someone please explain it to me?

Comment: not remotely enough information to know what you are talking about.  More than one 6502 "kit" existed in the last so many decades, predate zip files themselves, etc...

Comment: as far as programming a dev kit you read the dev kit docs, sometimes they provide the protocol information but not tools so you just make your own tools, or they dont do that and provide tools or somewhere in between.  but normally a 6502 is not programmable its the rom you have next to that is and that comes in countless flavors over time.  usually you pull the rom (eprom, eeprom) out of the board putting it in an eraser as needed then a programmer if reprogrammable and then you push it back into the socket on the board.

Comment: What zip file from where? Are you referring to the vasm tool download? Or your kit download?

Comment: Is it the Chibiakumas kit? It's actually pretty simple if so. Run ```Sdrive.bat``` then ```Notepad++.bat```. Once Notepad++ is open, you can press F6 on your keyboard to select which CPU to build for, and then the currently active file will be assembled and the appropriate emulator will run.